# How to make sure my google ads conversions are working?

Tags: google, advertising, google-ads, tracking, tags

I'm pretty new in the Google Ads world and I was, for the first time, setting up conversion links to know the different type of actions my users do.

I created conversions in the Google Ads backoffice, copy-pasted the code in my source (the global site tag & the event related to my action) and I also test my tracking tags with a chrome extension which is Tag Assistant where I can see all my conversion tags.

How do I make sure my conversion are really working?

Because when I check on the Google Ads backoffice, every conversion has the same status "No recent conversion" and in the "All conversions" column, I've got "0,00". So I'm expecting to see at least some data from when I went trigger the tag?

Am I in the wrong place to check this kind of thing?

Comment: It won't count the conversion unless you came into your website via clicking on one of your ads when you were testing it.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Thanks for your answer. For the conversion to count, I have to actually click on an external ad that lead me to my website and then, when I, for example, submit a form, the conversion will appear on my Google Ads dashboard ? Great, but is there another way to check that it is working properly without clicking an ad ?

Comment: That very much depends on how the conversion action is configured and implemented. I personally prefer to rely on Google Analytics for conversion actions, so I can see conversions from all traffic sources, that's much easier to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Google Analytics' real time feature and check if the conversion works in real time. As @GeoffAtkins mentioned, you'd need to click on a Google Ad --> then submit a form successfully on the website from that click (while in Google Analytics you can look at it in real time and see the click and the source of traffic medium as CPC). I am guessing there's a /thank-you type of page when form is submitted successfully that you can see you landed on and traffic source remained CPC.